# Why can't I compute a correct HMAC signature?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to compute an HMAC signature in Google Apps Script, but the documentation isn't 100% clear on how I need to pass in the parameters, and I have been unable to get the expected output.

---

To determine if I am getting correct output, I am comparing the result against known-good PHP code. That code is:

```
$key = "a2V5"; # this is "key" base64-encoded
$value = "test";
$result = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $value, base64_decode($key), true));
```

---

My code in Google Apps Script is:

```
key = "a2V5"; // this is "key" base64-encoded
value = "test";
result = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, value, Utilities.base64Decode(key)));
```

The output I expected to receive was:

```
KHoPuJp/vfpbVThjaRjlN6W4MGXk/zMSaLeqoRXd4EepsPT7W4KGCPwLYyfxAFX3Y3sFjp4Nu55piQGj5t1GHA==
```

But what I got instead was:

```
mGXJ3X/nH5ZIFUAPtf1PsViY50pD3cfU7J8w2KAIEAqrAgZ3dpKcuy5V1yvH4/C5n1C9rFFsKc2JKHTwUqPscQ==
```

What did I screw up here?

Comment: For future reference, [Google fixed this in June 19, 2018](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#june_19_2018) release of Google Apps Script.

Comment: Since the update now I have some HMACs that match PHP and some that don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reviewed your code and there is one thing which caught my eye:

`Utilities.base64Decode(key)` method returns `Byte[]`
`Utilities.computeHmacSignature(macAlgorithm, value, key)` accepts 3 parameters. `value` and `key` are of type `string`.

Maybe this is the issue. Why don't you try something like the following and check results then:

```
key = "a2V5"; // this is "key" base64-encoded
clearKey = "key";
value = "test";
result = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, value, clearKey));
```

I check Google Apps Script [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities?hl=en).

Comment: This gives the correct result. Though it means I have to go report a bug in the API, which is another story...

Comment: If you need to accept base64-encoded input, you can take the byte array output and loop over it using `String.fromCharCode` to build it back into a string.

Comment: Oh, that hurts my head. I'll probably do that, but it would be nice if Google would do things right the first time...

Comment: For future reference, I submitted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2227) to Google, and wound up using [jsSHA](http://caligatio.github.com/jsSHA/) in the project instead of Google's broken `Utilities.computeHmacSignature` method.

Comment: Miachael's suggestion of jsSHA works perfectly. I'll add that using a library in Google Scripts is counter-intuitive. Just paste `src/sha256.js` into a new file in your script and use `jsSHA` directly, without `require` and without using Google's library interface. Also, the bug report is still unresolved.