# Cryptopia API in Google Sheets (Google Apps Script)

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, authorization

In continuation of building Google SpreadSheet using Google Apps Script I've done with getting my Bittrex and Poloniex balances, but can't get to work with Cryptopia.

Here is a link to my struggles with Bittrex [Map JSON objects array to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833482/map-json-objects-array-to-strings/47887501#47887501)

Here is an official API links: https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Forum/Thread/256

Here are some examples:

1. https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Forum/Thread/262
2. https://github.com/Coac/cryptopia.js/blob/master/index.js
3. https://github.com/sigwo/node-cryptopia/blob/master/cryptopia.js

Here is my code, which getting "Invalid authorization header" error:

```
// Get Cryptopia balances
  var key = keys.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var secret = keys.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var baseUrl = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/';

  var command = "GetBalance";    
  var url = baseUrl + command;

  var signature = key + "POST" + encodeURIComponent(url).toLowerCase() + nonce;
  var hmacsignature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256,signature,secret);

  var header_value = "amx " + key + ":" + hmacsignature + ":" + nonce;
  var headers = { 'Authorization': header_value, 'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8' };

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetBalance", options);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your sample links, it seems that `hmacsignature` is encoded by base64. So how about the following modofication?

#### From :

```
var hmacsignature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256,signature,secret);
```

#### To :

```
var hmacsignature = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256,signature,secret));
```

#### Note :

- Is `nonce` declared? If you have not declared it, you can use a following script.

  - `var nonce = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);`

I cannot test this. So I don't know whether this works fine. If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

How about this? `var params = {};` might be required, even if there is no request parameters. So I added this and `Content-Length`. And then, is `secret` encoded by base64? I thought that it may be encoded from other scripts.

```
var key = keys.getRange("B4").getValue();
var secret = keys.getRange("C4").getValue();
var nonce = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000); // Added
var params = {}; // Added
var baseUrl = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/';
var command = "GetBalance";
var url = baseUrl + command;
var requestContentBase64String = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, JSON.stringify(params), Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)); // Added
var signature = key + "POST" + encodeURIComponent(url).toLowerCase() + nonce + requestContentBase64String; // Modified
var hmacsignature = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, signature, Utilities.base64Decode(secret), Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)); // Modified
var header_value = "amx " + key + ":" + hmacsignature + ":" + nonce;
var headers = {
  "Authorization": header_value,
  "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  "Content-Length" : Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(params)).getBytes().length // Added
};
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

Comment: Now it's returning 401 Error which means Not Authorized, but I'm providing correct key and secret.

Comment: @Sergey Sypalo Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Did the error message changed? I cannot test about this. So I would like to think of this situation from sample links. When I proposal a next modification, I will tell you. I'm really sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: Np, thx for the idea. I'll try to do the same in C# and run using debugging enabled. What to compare some working result with not working one varilble value by one to see what's wrong.

Comment: @Sergey Sypalo I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If this didn't work, I'm sorry. If the error message is changed, please tell me about it.

Comment: Thx again, now it looks better, but still complaining about Content-Length value. So I had to define another one variable cl = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(params)).getBytes().length and use it in headers. And when run debug script can't send the request because of unexpected value of cl variable, which value is "2.0"

Comment: @Sergey Sypalo I'm sorry for the inconvenience. For example, how about modifying ``Content-Length`` to ``"Content-Length" : 0``? Because there is no body in your case. ``Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(params)).getBytes().length`` means 2 bytes of ``{}``.

Answer (score 0):

`Utilities.computeHmacSignature(algorithm, value, key)` method does not compute the binary input correctly. The type of `value` and `key` parameter is `String`, but `Utilities.base64Decode`'s result is `Byte[]`. The raw binary value is changed while being converted from `Byte[]` to `String`.

Use [jsSHA](https://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/), and cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007167.

The following can be used to calculate the correct value, and fetch the result by  proper `UrlFetchApp.fetch`'s `options`.

```
.... paste src/sha256.js contents ...

...  
var params = {"Currency" : "BTC"};
...
var sha = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT");
sha.setHMACKey(secret, "B64");
sha.update(signature);
var hmacsignature = sha.getHMAC("B64");

var header_value = "amx " + key + ":" + hmacsignature + ":" + nonce;
var headers = {
  "Authorization" : header_value,
};

var options = {
  "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  "method": 'post',
  "headers": headers,
  "payload": JSON.stringify(params),
  "contentLength": JSON.stringify(params).length
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

Logger.log(json);
```