# Cryptopia API in Google Sheet - Signature does not match request parameters

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets

I am trying to connect to Cryptopia API to get my balance in Google Sheet and I can't make it work. The error I am currently getting is:

```
Signature does not match request parameters
```

[API Private Documentation](https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Forum/Thread/256)

My code:

```
  var key1 = "API_KEY";
  var secret1 = "API_SECRET";
  var nonce = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);  
  var params = {"Currency" : "BTC"};

  var url = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetBalance';
  var requestContentBase64String = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, JSON.stringify(params), Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)); // Added
  var signature = key1 + "POST" + encodeURIComponent(url).toLowerCase() + nonce + requestContentBase64String; // Modified
  var hmacsignature = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, signature, Utilities.base64Decode(secret1), Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)); // Modified
  var header_value = "amx " + key1 + ":" + hmacsignature + ":" + nonce;
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": header_value,
    "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    //"Content-Length" : Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(params)).getBytes().length // Added
  };
  var options = {
    "method": 'POST',
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(params),
    "contentLength": JSON.stringify(params).length
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response)
  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

There is one more [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890838/cryptopia-api-in-google-sheets-google-apps-script) regarding the same issue on stackoverflow but without correct answer.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using encodeURIComponent on the url? I can't see that being required in the docs, or lower casing it.

Comment: Have you solved this problem meanwhile?

Comment: I didn't solve it yet.. if you have any idea, would be very helpful - thanks!